# Deleting Information From Database String Input

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am looking to delete a particular row from a database using the code below. The code below is within a file called "delete.php" and it is taking input from an input box that is located on another php file called "yourReports.php".

When the form is submitted on "yourReports.php" it should delete the row from the database, however it doesn't appear to be working.

**delete.php**

```
<?php 

        $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "DBPASS","DBNAME") or die ('Could not connect to database!');   
        $_POST['delete'];
        $deletereport = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['delete']);

        mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM reports WHERE reportName = '".$deletereport."'");

        header('Location: yourreports.php');

?>
```

**yourReports.php**

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post" name="form1">
            <label><strong>Enter Report Name To Delete:</strong></label>
            <input name="delete"  id="delete" type="text">
            <input value="Delete Report" name="delete" class='myButton' type="submit">
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you forget to complete form tag => <form action="delete.php" 
must be <form action="delete.php" method="POST" >

Comment: I have put this code in and there is no change, it just refreshes the page and when i check the database the record is still present

Comment: stop header method and test value of $_post['delete']

Comment: i removed the header method and replaced it with your suggestion, when the form is posted it sends me to a blank white page, this white page is apparently "delete.php" from the address bar

Comment: you echo $_post['delete'] to check value you send

Comment: it says "Delete Report" when submitting the form on a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the method and name attribute of form to post

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post" name="form1">
```

Check if the query fails:

```
if(! mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM reports WHERE reportName = '".$deletereport."'")){
  echo mysqli_error();
}
```

[Updated]

You cannot have two inputs with the same name. Your input and delete button both have the name `delete`. So try considering different names for inputs.

Comment: I have put this code in and there is no change, it just refreshes the page and when i check the database the record is still present

Comment: hi i checked for the query fail but i am not shown any error message and am sent to a white blank page called "delete.php"

Comment: can you echo $_POST['delete'] at top in delete.php

Comment: it echos the text "Delete Report" on a blank page, this is the value of my button

Comment: Have updated the answer. You cannot have two inputs with same name. if  so then the latter's value will be considered. i think this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you very much! the solution worked. That should have been obvious to me from the start, major oversight. Sometimes need a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM reports WHERE reportName = '".$deletereport."'");
```

To

```
  mysqli_query($mysqli,"DELETE FROM reports WHERE reportName = '{$deletereport}'");
```